# How can I select unique record with latest created date?

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have following data set

```
1   ID_TRA  ID_CM   DATE
2   369387  31715   27. 11. 2017 9:49:13
3   369387  31341   27. 2. 2017 13:33:55
4   369503  31715   27. 11. 2017 9:49:13
5   369503  9810    11. 10. 2010 21:59:28
6   369503  31715   27. 11. 2017 9:49:13
7   369503  9810    11. 10. 2010 21:59:28
8   433605  29760   24. 4. 2015 7:57:46
9   433605  31715   6. 12. 2017 20:26:36
10  433605  9810    29. 3. 2015 11:10:44
```

I need to first group by "id_tra" and then show the latest date for corresponding id_tra, so the output would be something like this:

```
369387  27. 11. 2017 9:49:13
369503  27. 11. 2017 9:49:13
433605  6. 12. 2017 20:26:36
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Unrelated, but: `DATE` is a horrible name for a column. For one because it's also a keyword, but more importantly: it doesn't document what the column contains. A start date? An end  date? A due date? A registration date?  A birth date?

Answer (score 4):

Hmm... it would be difficult to do. Something like

```
select id_tra, max("date")
from "table"
group by id_tra
```

isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
SELECT ID_TRA, MAX("date") As MaximumDate
FROM Table
Group by ID_TRA
```

Comment: Does Oracle really support square brackets for delimited identifiers?

Comment: `date` is a reserved word, i.e. it needs to be delimited as `"date"`.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try running the below -

```
select id_tra, max(date) from table_name group by id_tra
```

Comment: `date` is a reserved word, i.e. it needs to be delimited as `"date"`.